# How do I find the longest sentence and the average sentence length in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

After I input a few sentences in a textbox, I need to find the longest sentence in the textbox by clicking a button. The longest sentence should be displayed in a MessageBox.

Another button should display in a MessageBox the average length of the sentences.

Comment: For both, just sort the sentences, then, depending on how you sorted pick the first or last element, as the longest, then the average is either going to be the element at size/2 or you may need to calculate the length and find the one that is closest. It depends on how you define average sentence.

Comment: Is this for school work? If so, I think you should try and show us what thought you have put into this already. Otherwise, you can cut-and-paste the answers below, but what will you have learnt? If you want to be a programmer, solving problems is 90% of the job.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm new to this, but I'll try to help!

I'd look at splitting the sentences entered in the textbox to an array or list, and then process that.

```
Dim sentences As String()

sentences = TextBox1.Text.Split("?")
Dim avgSum As Double = 0
Dim avg As Integer = 0
Dim longest As Integer = 0

For Each sentence As String In sentences
    If sentence.Length < longest Then longest = sentence.Length
    avgSum = avgSum + sentence.Length
Next
avg = avgSum / sentences.Length

MsgBox("Average is: " + avg)
MsgBox("Longest is: " + longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define three functions: the first function to extract all the sentences, the second to determine the longest sentence, and the third to determine the average sentence length.

**Extract all sentences**

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Extracts all sentences from a text block. It is assumed that a sentence is terminated by either a period (.), a question mark (?), or an exclamation mark (!).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="text">The text block as string.</param>
    ''' <returns>An array of sentences.</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function sentences(ByVal text As String) As String()
        Dim snts(Len(text)) As String
        Dim curPeriodPos As Integer
        Dim nextPeriodPos As Integer
        Dim longestSnt As String
        Dim nextSnt As String
        Dim i As Integer

        text = text + " "
        text = Replace(text, "? ", ". ")
        text = Replace(text, "! ", ". ")

        curPeriodPos = InStr(text, ". ")
        longestSnt = Mid(text, 1, curPeriodPos)
        i = 0
        Do While curPeriodPos + 1 < Len(text)
            nextPeriodPos = InStr(curPeriodPos + 1, text, ". ")
            nextSnt = Mid(text, curPeriodPos + 1, nextPeriodPos - curPeriodPos + 1)
            snts(i) = nextSnt
            i += 1
            curPeriodPos = nextPeriodPos
        Loop

        Return snts
    End Function
```

**Determine longest sentence**

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines the longest sentence among an array of senetences.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sentencesArray">A string array of sentences.</param>
    ''' <returns> A sentence as string.</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function longestSentence(ByVal sentencesArray() As String) As String
        Dim longestSnt As String = ""

        For Each sentence As String In sentencesArray
            If Len(sentence) > Len(longestSnt) Then
                longestSnt = sentence
            End If
        Next sentence

        Return longestSnt
    End Function
```

**Determine average sentence length**

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines the average sentence length of sentences in an array of sentences.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sentencesArray">A string array of sentences.</param>
    ''' <returns>An integer representing the average sentence length.</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function averageSentenceLength(ByVal sentencesArray() As String) As Double
        Dim sentenceLengths(sentencesArray.Length) As Integer
        Dim total As Integer = 0
        Dim average As Double
        Dim counter As Integer = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To sentencesArray.Length - 1
            sentenceLengths(i) = Len(sentencesArray(i))
            If sentenceLengths(i) > 0 Then
                total += sentenceLengths(i)
                counter += 1
            End If
        Next i

        average = CDbl(total) / CDbl(counter)

        Return average
    End Function
```

These functions can be called in the buttons's event handlers as follows:

```
Private Sub DisplayLongestSentence() Handles longestSententeceButton.Click
    Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text
    MessageBox.Show(longestSentence(sentences(text)))
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayAverageSentenceLength() Handles averageSententeceLengthButton.Click
    Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text
    MessageBox.Show(averageSentenceLength(sentences(text)))
End Sub
```